# Opening custom protocol URL doesn't work consistently in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, url

The following code supposes to open a URL in an external app:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'myprotocol:jdoe@example.com;fromuser=John%20Doe;mode=audiovideo';

document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

When the app is not installed, on some PCs Chrome fails silently while on the others it displays this window:

[image: Launch]

Where is this behavior defined?

Comment: Did you find the answer to this? I have same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Application association to URI Schema

If you want to register your app to handle a specific URI Schema in Windows, then you should register it in registry. It is explained in [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx) and Googling "[Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](https://www.google.com/search?q=Registering%20an%20Application%20to%20a%20URI%20Scheme)" gives plenty of examples.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/
  your-protocol-name/
    (Default)    "URL:your-protocol-name Protocol"
    URL Protocol ""
    shell/
      open/
        command/
          (Default) PathToExecutable
```

---

## Web App schema registration

You can [register a custom protocol handler](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/06/Registering-a-custom-protocol-handler?hl=en) with Google Chrome using `navigator.registerProtocolHandler` (Firefox has the feature too).

```
navigator.registerProtocolHandler(
    'web+mystuff', 'http://example.com/rph?q=%s', 'My App');
```

Please note, that your protocol has to start with `web+`. Otherwise you would get `SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18` error.

Or, if you are developing a Chrome App, then you can [register your handlers](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/url_handlers) in your manifest file.

```
"url_handlers": {
  "view_foo_presentation": {
    "matches": [
      "https://www.foo.com/presentation/view/*"
    ],
    "title": "View Foo presentation"
  }
}
```

You can also look into the Chrome URLs (`chrome://chrome-urls/`) and see if you can change it in any of the settings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not what I looking for. I am aware of `registerProtocolHandler`, but I want to open a desktop app, not a webapp.

Comment: @Pavlo that's called URI Schema registration. I added an example and links on how to do it in Windows. I guess that's your target OS.

Comment: I know how to implement it. My question is about Chrome behaviour.